# A special boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am looking for a solution to this boundary value problem, or some reference where i can find informations
\begin{align*}
y''(x) - \varepsilon y''(\pi-x) + \lambda y(x) =0,&\quad 0<x<\pi \\
 y(0)=y(\pi)=0, & \quad |\varepsilon|>1,\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
I tried to make it a system by setting

$$y_1(x)=y(x),\quad y_2(x)=y(\pi-x)$$
this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Gonçalo thank you i will try. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: This is called a functional differential equation, since it involves the unknown function $y(x)$ evaluated at multiple arguments. You can find entire books on the solutions of these types of equations.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks again.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Thnak you.